# Gitlab-CI: set environment variables for both Linux and Windows

Tags: bash, cmd, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a project that needs to be able to be built through a Gitlab-Runner on either Linux *or* Windows using the same `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the Git repository. It's a simple build and I just want to use the `shell` executor.

The problem is that the syntax for setting environment variables in *bash* (Linux) is different from *cmd* (Windows). One uses `export` the other `set`.

How can I set up my environment without resorting to setting up a different `config.toml` on each runner? (Which also seems buggy on Linux when it comes to modifying `$PATH`, but that's another issue.)

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of the common `||` syntax for conditional execution in both shells to write commands that will fall through on one OS but not on the other. In the case of setting environment variables the fact that the `export` does not exist in `cmd` can be exploited to create a sort-of-dirty OS check:

```bash
export PATH="$MYPATH/:$PATH" || set "PATH=%MYPATH%\;%PATH%"
```

The first half will execute correctly on Linux, but throw an error on Windows. The `||` syntax is common to both shells and will execute the succeeding statement *only* when the preceding one fails. So the second half will only execute on Windows, since `export` will only fail in `cmd` (provided of course that the syntax is correct on the Linux side).

A complete `.gitlab-ci.yml` might look like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - release

before_script:
  # set environment for both Linux (first half) and Windows (second half)
  - export PATH="$MYPATH/:$PATH" || set "PATH=%MYPATH%\;%PATH%"

my-app:
  stage: release
  script:
    - ./gradlew build
```